# Cant see the listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to bind my listview through an array adapter. I have my listview in a layout

**activity_menu.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/saltnpepper"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:paddingTop="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"><TextView></TextView></TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

    </ListView>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Then I have another layout with TextView to load in the listView

**menulist.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/nameText"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

In my code I am doing the following but my list view has never loaded once

```
    ArrayList<String> alTest = new ArrayList<String>();
alTest.add("One");
alTest.add("Two");

ArrayAdapter<String> catAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menulist, R.id.nameText, alTest);
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
list.setAdapter(catAdapter);
```

I have also tried simple array instead of arraylist alTest but didnt work

Comment: You something have in your `Logs` show that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was not that listview wasn't loading but that the imageview before it was covering more screen!! also Now i have another problem (posting on a new thread)

```
<TableRow android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/saltnpepper"                
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
    </TableRow>
```

The image doesnot expand the whole width of screen